# Swift - Exit outer function from closure

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Kotlin, you can return from an outer function from a closure.

```
   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     val letters = listOf("A", "B", "C")

     fun lookForLetter(letter: String, letters: List<String>){
        letters.forEach { l ->
          if (l == letter) {
            println("Found")
            return
          }
          println(l)
        }
        println("Completed")
      }

      lookForLetter("A", letters = letters)
   }
```

Output:

Found

In Swift, return exits execution of the closure

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C"]

func lookForLetter(letter: String, letters: [String]) {
    letters.forEach { (l) in
        if l == letter {
            print("Found");
            return
        }
        print(l)
    }
    print("Completed")
}

lookForLetter(letter: "A", letters: letters)
```

Output:

Found

B

C

Completed

Is there a way to achieve the same result in Swift?

Comment: The Swift code you posted can be written in much better ways. Are you simply using this code as a contrived example to demonstrate your question or do you simply want to find any way to write the method so it find the letter with any appropriate code?

Comment: @rmaddy It's just an example to demonstrate. I'm currently learning Kotlin and found it interesting that a return without a label exits the entire function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift does not have non-local returns from closures. In other words, there is no direct way to return out of multiple levels. This only works with inlined functions in Kotlin, but Swift does not have this distinction.

There are other collection methods which stop once an element is found, for example `index(where:)`.

```
func lookForLetter(letter: String, letters: [String]) {
    guard let _ = letters.index(where: { (l) in
        if l == letter {
            print("Found");
            return true
        }
        print(l)
        return false
    }) else {
        print("Completed")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, someone that understood the question (at least the same way I did).

Comment: If you don't need the index, then just us `contains(where:)`

Comment: Info about inlined functions was another detail that I missed. Thank you, This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @GregoryProsper You may be interested to learn that Scala allows for non-local returns without inlining. It's implemented behind the scenes by throwing a special [exception](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/NonLocalReturnControl.html). Trade-offs, though: poor performance and unexpected effects if the closure is stored and called from a different stack frame. (IMO, it's a good thing Kotlin and Swift did not choose to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

Hey in swift you do like this

```
func lookForLetter(letter: String, letters: [String]) {
for l in letters {
    if l == letter {
        print("Found");
        return;
    }
    print(l)
}
print("Completed")
```

}

also

> Using the forEach method is distinct from a for-in loop in two important ways:
>
> 1. You cannot use a break or continue statement to exit the current call of the body closure or skip subsequent calls.
> 2. Using the return statement in the body closure will exit only from the current call to body, not from any outer scope, and won’t skip subsequent calls.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach